# Split [rust] tag into [rust0.9], [rust0.8] etc

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The Rust programming languages changes a lot between versions.

Maybe we should use separate tags for different versions of Rust? Compare with [perl] and [perl6].

Comment: You can add those tags, or someone can.  C# has a tag, but there are also version-specific tags.

Comment: Another example: `[python]`, `[python-2.x]`, `[python-3.x]` and then on to `[python-2.6]`, `[python-2.7]`, `[python-3.3]`, etc.

Comment: Few people subscribe to the version-specific tags but they do help in clarifying what version the OP is talking about when it comes to certain syntax and available library functionality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I suppose I forgot the - in the tag in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added [rust0.8](/questions/tagged/rust0.8) and [rust0.9](/questions/tagged/rust0.9) and provided for both just the wiki excerpt. I'll leave it to a subject matter expert to provide the tag wiki's.

I skimmed through the [rust](/questions/tagged/rust) questions and (re)tagged those where it yelled the version at me. For sure more questions need a version specific tag but I leave that as well to a subject matter expert.